# PySpark: Empty a table and keep the schema and constraints

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyspark

I want to empty a table with PySpark but I don't want to lose or destroy its structure, schema and constraints.

How can I do this with PySpark/JDBC?

In my example I have an F_EVENTS table (table of facts for some events) and an D_CUSTOMER table (table of dimension for my customer). My constraints are:

- F_EVENTS.pk_event is my primary key and auto-increments.
- F_EVENTS.fk_customer is a foreign key to my table D_CUSTOMERS

Here is how I currently empty this F_EVENT table:

```
cols = ["pk_event", "fk_customer", "information"]
field = [StructField(f, StringType(), True) for f in cols]
schema = StructType(field)

sc = spark.sparkContext
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

df.write.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://blah.windows.net:1433;database=myDB;user=myself;password=hunter2", 
    "dbo.F_EVENTS", mode = "overwrite")
```

And here is how I create my table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[F_EVENTS](
    [pk_event] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fk_customer] [int] NOT NULL,
    [information] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_EVENTS] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_event] ASC
) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_EVENTS]  
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_event_customer] FOREIGN KEY([fk_customer])
REFERENCES [dbo].[D_CUSTOMERS] ([pk_customer])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_EVENTS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_event_customer]
GO
```

Comment: Looks like you already have a solution.  Is your existing solution working?  If not, what errors / problems are you facing?

Comment: Yes, totally forgot to explain why my current solution doesn't suit me. running the above code destroys the schema and the constraints. That is to say, `pk_event` does not auto increment anymore, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't overwrite. Replace `mode = "overwrite"` with `mode = "append"`.
If you need to empty it, just run a `delete` prior to your `write`.

Comment: "appending" won't empty my table, I'm over-writing in order to empty my table. How would I run a "delete"?

Comment: you are connecting to a sql-server db. You have tons of libs to access it and run the commands you need. [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi) for example. It is more difficult to do that in pure Spark. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576874/delete-functionality-with-spark-sql-dataframe)

Comment: yes, I'm aware that there are lots of libraries to access and modify SQL Server databases, I was asking specifically about PySpark.